# crystalreporting in c#

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I want to use crystal report in vs2010.but when i try to create crystal report by 
    right click on project and adding new item,following message show.

```
"CRYSTAL REPORTS® FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2010

 Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 is a free download for adding presentation     
 quality reports to WPF, WinForms, and ASP.Net Web Sites.

Major new features include:

64-bit runtime 
 WPF viewer 
Enhanced embedded report designer
```

Support for exporting to XLSX 
     Learn more and download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 today.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install Crystal Reports for VS2010 through this link: http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp